# JSTree isnt showing node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I used the document from jstree page.I want to use it in my laravel project so when i click on a root node it will show the child of that node  but when i insert this here i dont know why the button doesnt work.It works if i do it just the html form but not when i use extends (layouts.master).It shows the child node and the root node but not with their styles and the button doesnt work.Thanks in advance

masters.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    @yield('title')
  </title> 
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../assets/css/now-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.5.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{  asset('assets/css/dataTables.min.css') }}">
  <!--jstree-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />

</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="wrapper ">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="orange">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="simple-text logo-normal">
          Company
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class=" {{ 'dashboard' == request()->path() ? 'active' : '' }} ">
            <a href="/dashboard">
              <i class="now-ui-icons design_app"></i>
              <p>Dashboard</p>
            </a>
          </li>          
          <li class=" {{ 'role-register' == request()->path() ? 'active' : '' }} ">
            <a href="/role-register">
              <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
              <p>Employee Profile</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class=" {{ 'department' == request()->path() ? 'active' : '' }} ">
            <a href="/department">
              <i class="now-ui-icons design_bullet-list-67"></i>
              <p>Department</p>
            </a>
          </li>                   
          <li>
            <a href="/home">
              <i class="now-ui-icons text_caps-small"></i>
              <p>Your Profile</p>
            </a>
          </li>  
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel" id="main-panel">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent  bg-primary  navbar-absolute">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar-toggle">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation">
            <form>
              <div class="input-group no-border">
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_zoom-bold"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                  {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>                
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                  onclick="event.preventDefault();
                  document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                  {{ __('Logout') }}
                </a>                
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                  @csrf
                </form>
              </div>
            </li> 
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/home">
                <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
                <p>
                  <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Account</span>
                </p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navbar -->    
    <div class="panel-header panel-header-sm">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      @yield('content')      
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">     
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>

<!--jstree-->
<!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
  // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
  $('#jstree').jstree();
  // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
  $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.selected);
  });
  // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
    $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
    $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
  });
});
</script>
<!--jstree-->



<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="../assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{  asset('assets/js/dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js"></script>
<!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
<!-- Control Center for Now Ui Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
<script src="../assets/js/now-ui-dashboard.min.js?v=1.5.0" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- Now Ui Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
<script src="../assets/demo/demo.js"></script>
@yield('scripts')

</body>

</html>
```

page.blade.php

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
Employee Management | Admin
@endsection

@section('content')
  <!-- 3 setup a container element -->
  <div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li>Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
          <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button>demo button</button>

  <!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function () {
    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree').jstree();
    // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      console.log(data.selected);
    });
    // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
    $('button').on('click', function () {
      $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
      $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
      $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
    });
  });
  </script>
  @endsection

  @section('scripts')
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable();
  } );
  @endsection
```

Comment: Did you add jsTree plugin script link?

Comment: i changed it with the cdn version and it works thank you :)